# React Navigation - navigating to another tab and reset stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to route from one StackNavigator to another, both of which are inside a TabNavigator. I'm currently able to get there by simply doing:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen3')
```

But I also want to reset that tab when I go to it. Here is how my app navigators are generally set up:

```
- Main (StackNavigator)
  - LoginScreen
  - MainTabs (TabNavigator)
    - Tab1 (StackNavigator)
      - Screen1
      - Screen2
    - Tab2 (StackNavigator)
      - Screen3
      - Screen4
```

How could I navigate to `Screen3` but also reset the StackNavigator `Tab2`?

I've also tried doing this, to no avail:

```
let resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: 'Tab2',
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Screen3' })
  ],
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Comment: I can confirm that this does not work in the latest version.

Comment: @TIMEX, please upload a reproduction repository of your issue on Gitlab or Github. I have some experience in `React Native` and `React Navigation`. I can help you. -- reproduction repository: a minimized version of your project that has the issue.

Comment: How could I navigate to Screen3 but also reset the StackNavigator Tab2? Do you want this to happen when you click on Tab2?

Answer (score 21):

You'll have to dispatch two navigation actions, one to reset the stack of the current tab and another to navigate to the next screen:

```
let resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Screen1' })
  ],
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen3');
```

Here is a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/rynZqcwqQ)

Comment: won't that reset the first tab instead of the tab you're navigating to?

Comment: Perfect Answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but it works for by resetting the whole tab navigator, like
let resetAction = StackActions.reset({
index: 0,
actions: [
NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'tabScreen' }),                                            ] });
                                        this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
                                        this.props.navigation.navigate('Cart')

Comment: This answer is outdated. V5 does not use `actions` anymore, rather `routes`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the advanced `action` of the [`navigate`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html#navigate) api combined with the [Navigator dependant functions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigator-dependent-functions) **without** using any *additional action or navigation call*.

Here is an example

```
navigateWithReset = (routeName) => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      action: this.props.navigation.popToTop(),
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  };
```

The working snack link can be found [**here**](https://snack.expo.io/@pritishvaidya94/react-navigation-test).

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I solved this using [NavigationService](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html):

```
NavigationService.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: null, // required to reset tabs
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: 'MainTabs',
      action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Tab2' }),
    }),
  ],
});
NavigationService.navigate({
  key: 'Screen3',
  routeName: 'Screen3',
});
```

pay attention to the 'key: null' option, this made it work

Comment: This solution is perfect. Here's how I did it in react-navigation V4,
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: 'xxx',
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: MainTabs, 
    action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Tab2' }) 
    }),
  ],
});
navigation.dispatch(resetAction);

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to navigate to the Tab and then reset to the screen you want

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Tab2');
let resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate(
      {
        routeName: 'Screen3',
        params: {},
        key: Math.random() + 'Screen3'
      }
    )
  ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is based on your stack architecture, however, you should navigate after your `resetAction` dispatching.

After `resetAction` dispatching use below code:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen3');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, here is the code that worked for me:-

```
    let resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Screen1' })
      ],
    });

    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);   // <---- 1
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Tab2');   // <---- 2 
    (IMPORTANT: Here in Line marked as 2, I have used tab name not screen name)
```

Firstly, I am resetting the current tab and pushing the initial route so that when I come back to this tab, it should land me to the given initial route [Line No. marked as 1]. Then, I am navigating to another tab which lands me to its initial route [Line No. marked as 2].

Comment: This answer is outdated. V5 does not use `actions` anymore, rather `routes`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with React Navigation 5.x

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66982007/10672805

The code below is for resetting multiple tabs.

```
TabNavigator
    Tab1: 'tab1_name' 
      StackNavigator
         - ScreenA
         - ScreenB

    Tab2: 'tabs_name'
      StackNavigator
         - ScreenC
         - ScreenD

    Tab3: 'tab3_name'
      StackNavigator
         - ScreenE
         - ScreenF
```

```js
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'tab1_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenA' },
            { name: 'ScreenB' },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'tab2_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenC' },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'tab3_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenE' },
            { name: 'ScreenF' },
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  })
)
```

And with this code, the first page you see is `tab1_name` tab's `ScreenB` screen.

So, if you want to see `tab3_name` tab's `ScreenF` screen first after running the dispatch function, the code should be something like:

```js
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'tab3_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenE' },
            { name: 'ScreenF' },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'tab1_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenA' },
            { name: 'ScreenB' },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'tab2_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenC' },
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  })
)
```

By the way, when you write down the `routes` of tab's `state`, it should follow the sequence of page stack. So that it would work as you expected.

```js
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'tab3_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            // { name: 'ScreenE' },   // removed
            { name: 'ScreenF' },
          ]
        }
      },
      ...
```

If you omit the first stack page as above, `ScreenE` is not accessible but only `ScreenF` after running the dispatch function.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

if you are wroking on tabs and then want to reset the tab then try this
React Navigation 5
here is the link [here is documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#unmountonblur)

```
 <BottomTab.Screen
    name="Post"
    component={PostStack}
    options={{
      unmountOnBlur: true,// set this props in your tab screen options
      title: 'Post',
      tabBarIcon: focused => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="Post" />,
    }}
  />
```

Comment: This effectively unmounts the entire tab, causing it to reload everytime you open it again, which is not what most people (including myself) are after as it introduces a lot of other side effects.

Comment: then you can follow this link. here are some of the navigation events that will help you https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/