# How to reset a Stack in a different Tab using React Navigation 5.x

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

My app has a TabNavigator with a StackNavigator in each Tab. I'm not resetting the stacks when navigating between them by clicking on different tabs, so when you change tab, the stack contains the previous state. However, occasionally from within a Screen in one Tab, I want to navigate to a specific Screen in a different tab, and on that occasion, I want to reset the stack in the target Tab.

```
TabNavigator
    Tab1 
      StackNavigator
         - ScreenA
         - ScreenB
    Tab2
      StackNavigator
         - Screen1
         - Screen2
```

I want to be able to put a button on Screen2 that resets the Stack on Tab1.

I was wondering if the "target" parameter mentioned in the docs here might help, but there's no  examples of how to use it. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/

(I have searched on here but answers suggested for 4.x don't seem to apply anymore). 
Thanks!

Comment: No answer yet hey? Reading that using this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset might be on the right track but I can not find a solution

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @VictorMolina I have posted an answer below - it's a while ago now but this is roughly the approach I took

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the end I was able to use the `reset` action to do this. I dispatched nested state for the tab I wanted to reset:

```
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'tab-route-name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'stack-route-1' },
            { name: 'stack-route-2' },
            { name: 'stack-route-3' }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  })
)
```

It seems to be clever enough that as long as the tab navigator is a parent of the current route, it will find it and reset it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @anorakgirl. it works perfectly!
I want to add some other cases people might want to know. Since the app usually consists of 4-5 tabs.

The code below is for resetting multiple tabs.

```
TabNavigator
    Tab1: 'tab1_name' 
      StackNavigator
         - ScreenA
         - ScreenB

    Tab2: 'tabs_name'
      StackNavigator
         - ScreenC
         - ScreenD

    Tab3: 'tab3_name'
      StackNavigator
         - ScreenE
         - ScreenF
```

```js
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'tab1_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenA' },
            { name: 'ScreenB' },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'tab2_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenC' },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'tab3_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenE' },
            { name: 'ScreenF' },
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  })
)
```

And with this code, the first page you see is `tab1_name` tab's `ScreenB` screen.

So, if you want to see `tab3_name` tab's `ScreenF` screen first after running the dispatch function, the code should be something like:

```js
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'tab3_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenE' },
            { name: 'ScreenF' },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'tab1_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenA' },
            { name: 'ScreenB' },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'tab2_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenC' },
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  })
)
```

By the way, when you write down the `routes` of tab's `state`, it should follow the sequence of page stack. So that it would work as you expected.

```js
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'tab3_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            // { name: 'ScreenE' },   // removed
            { name: 'ScreenF' },
          ]
        }
      },
```

If you omit the first stack page as above, `ScreenE` is not accessible but only `ScreenF` after running the dispatch function.

Hope this works for you.